# Passing display value format to angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, string, formatting

I would like to pass the formatting of a display value to an angular component.

For example:

```
format="'(utc, offset) location (tz)'" === '(UTC -04:00) New York (EDT)'
```

or

```
format="'(tz, offset) location'" === '(EDT -04:00) New York'
```

The idea is that the value will be displayed as per the format given, parentheses included. 
I'm guessing the best way to acheive this would be to have an array of the format required?
So given the following string, how can I generate the following array:

```
'(utc, offset) location (tz)' === ['(', 'utc-code', 'offset-hours', ')', 'location', '(', 'tz-code', ')'];

'(tz, offset) location' === ['(', 'tz', 'offset', ')', 'location']
```

Comment: Create a [custom date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Comment: Which component are you using? Is it your code? Please, post its skeleton

Comment: It's a custom component, that displays a list of timezones. The idea is to give component user the ability to dictate how the display value is formatted.

Comment: Do you need to write logic for formatting the display value or it is already written in component? 
is it angular1? - component or directive?
or angular 2?

Comment: It's an angular 1 component. Maybe to start I just need to workout how to convert the string '(utc, offset) location (tz)' into an array that looks like ['(', 'utc-code', 'offset-hours', ')', 'location', '(', 'tz-code', ')'], as I have a decent idea of what to do after that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use component `binding` to pass the value. Here `$doCheck` will be called in each digest cycle which provides an opportunity to detect and act on changes to the bindings.

I have written a simple logic with regular expression to display the data with input format. Hope this approach would helps instead of your array approach.

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('appCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.format = '(offset) location (tz)';
})
.component('myComponent', {
  template: '<div>{{$ctrl.formattedValue}}</div>',
  controller: myComponentCtrl,
  bindings: {
    format: '='
  }
});

function myComponentCtrl(/*your DI goes here*/){
  console.log('log from component: format->'+this.format);
  var self = this;
  this.formattedValue = '';
  
  this.$doCheck = function(){ 
    var sampleDateObject = {
      tz: 'CDT',
      offset: '-4:00',
      location: 'Chicago',
      year: 2017
    }
    self.formattedValue = self.format.replace(/([a-z]+)/gi, function(match){
      return sampleDateObject[match]?sampleDateObject[match]:match;
    });
  };
}

myComponentCtrl.$inject = [/*your DI goes here as string*/];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <my-component format="format"></my-component>
  <my-component format="'(tz, offset) location, year'"></my-component>
</div>
```

Comment: This replace function is exactly the sort of thing I was after. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my badly worded question.